# sql basic join table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ID      Date      Spend
1   01/01/1990    $x1
2   01/01/1990    $x2
2   01/03/1990    $x3
```

I'm a sql beginner and could someone help me to solve this question?I'd appreciate it!

if we want to just consider the date after the year of 2000, how can we find the ID which has tenth highest spend by using the method of Join?

Using my basic sql knowledge,this is what I have coded:

```
select ID, SUM(Spend)
    From(
    select ID,SUM(Spend)
    from table A, table B
    WHERE A.ID=B.ID
    AND Date => 01/01/2000;
)
Order by SUM(Spend) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: You need to define the columns of Tables A and Tables B for us to provide a query.

Comment: You should never have a comma in your FROM statement. If that's what your SQL book or tutorial is teaching, find a better instruction source.

Comment: The_Outsider is right, and we also need to know: *what is the problem* (this is most important) and *what variant of SQL you're using* (SQL Server/TSQL, MySQL etc.). I can spot a whole bunch of things that are probably giving you issues, but without knowing what error you're seeing or what language you're writing in I can't give a very good solution.

Comment: select ID
    From(
    select ID, Spend, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Spend DESC) Ranking
    from table A inner join table B
    on A.ID=B.ID
    AND Date >= '01/01/2000';
) X
WHERE Ranking = 10

Comment: @Jeff I'm using MySQL and this is whole question and table which my instructor gave me.

Comment: @The_Outsider that's the whole table which my instructor gave me.

Comment: @Amit thanks for your help

Comment: @Amit: does MySQL support `dense_rank`?

Comment: no. but as per internet search, alternative can be created for dense_rank. I responded according to SQL server since it was not mentioned earlier which db he is on.

Comment: @Andomar yes , it does

Comment: Don't think so, you're probably on Oracle or SQL Server :)

Comment: Yeah, you seem to not know which RDBMS you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an [example](http://rextester.com/EWRR68107):

```
select  a.ID
,       SUM(Spend) as SumSpend
from    tableA a
join    tableB b
on      a.ID = b.ID
where   '2000-01-01' <= date
group by
        a.ID
order by
        SumSpend desc
limit   1
offset  2
```

- `group by` tells MySQL which groups of rows to `sum`
- You can use [`limit 1 offset 9`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to get the tenth row
- If you select a column that is in two tables, you have to specify which table (`a.ID` above)
- In SQL a date is a string in single quotes

Comment: So if I change the column name of date to other name, I do not need to add quote, right?

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you! I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @Strawberry: Cool, both right, in MySQL you quote keywords with backticks (or double quotes if you `set session sql_mode='ansi';`)